# How to make channel and add someone to it

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wanted to know how can I make a channel in a server using discord.py and add a person to that channel and send messages in that channel. I am trying to make a ModMail bot, here is my code if you wanted to have a look at it:

```
@bot.command()
async def new(ctx,reason):
    AuthorID = str(ctx.author.id)
    try:
        await ctx.send('@Staff <@{AuthorID}'>
        await ctx.send("Please leave your question here our support team will be with you soon!")
    except commands.MissingRequiredArgument:
        await ctx.send('You are missing a required argument `reason`')
```

If you think I am not clear enough or find any grammar/spelling mistakes (English is not my first language) please edit the post

Answer (score 0):

You can create a text channel using [`Guild.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel), which takes an `overwrites` parameter. Then you can use [`PermissionOverwrite`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.PermissionOverwrite) to create channel specific permissions.

```
@client.command()
async def newticket(ctx, *, reason):
    guild = ctx.message.guild
    channel_name = f"{ctx.author.name}s Ticket"
    staff_mention, member_mention = "<@&730099343972892733>", ctx.author.mention
    
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),  # @everyone
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),  # Bot itself
        guild.get_member(ctx.author.id): discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)  # Member
    }
    
    try:
        channel = await guild.create_text_channel(channel_name, overwrites=overwrites, reason=reason)
        await channel.send(f"{staff_mention} {member_mention}\n"
                           f"Please leave your question here our support team will be with you soon!")
    except commands.MissingRequiredArgument:
        await ctx.send('You are missing a required argument `reason`')
```